# Concatenating results from many if statements into a new column [Power Query]

Tags: powerquery, m

I have a column "Group Membership" that contains many tags. I want to search to see if a tag is mentioned in this column or not. If yes, I want to add it to a list separated by a comma in a new column.

I got started with this:

```
let

...

    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Moved Prefix", "Custom", each 
  if (Text.Contains([Group Membership], "Japanese Language") then "Japanese, " else null) &
  if (Text.Contains([Group Membership], "English Language") then "English, " else null) &

...

)

in
    #"Added Conditional Column"
```

But the syntax seems wrong. Can somebody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think your parentheses aren't placed quite right and you probably want to use an empty string rather than null.

Try this instead:

```
let

...

    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Moved Prefix", "Custom", each 
  (if Text.Contains([Group Membership], "Japanese Language") then "Japanese, " else "") &
  (if Text.Contains([Group Membership], "English Language") then "English, " else "") &

...

)

in
    #"Added Conditional Column"
```